# Why is the pattern buffer in Star Trek not routinely used to revive people?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter

Seeing as Commander Riker was restored using the transporter pattern buffer, when assumed dead, why is this not always used when someone dies? I guess for dramatic purposes it wouldn't be very interesting if no one ever was under the threat of dying, but is there any explanation in the series itself?

Comment: Which episode are you referring to? This happened several times under different circumstances

Comment: Riker was duplicated once, but I don't recall anything like what you're describing...